# Get R markdown chunk dependencies

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Is there any pkg/function in R that can return all the Rmd chunk dependencies, including all the dependencies that will be included in the ? I am making a JSON file that keeps all the chunk information from code to output etc and I am not sure if I can capture the script/style (HTML Dependency) for each chunk that automatically added into the  by html_document. For example, when we run `library(DT)`, it comes with some `datatable` dependencies.

Comment: With that example, one can do `packageDescription("DT")[c("Imports","Suggests")]` as a start.

Comment: (That last comment assumes you parsed the chunk and found `library(DT)`. If that's also your concern, then my comment only helps advise the next step.)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. I think it requires a deep understanding how `knitr` works to evaluate a chunk. It probably convert the rmd chunk and also added the html Dependecy in the head that I am looking for something like a hook that we can get back the information supposed to be added into the <head>.